# Openerp add button in a tree view to create one2many field

Tags: forms, button, tree, odoo

I have one2many relation between moudle1 and mosule2. I want to add a button having the same behavior as the one2emany "add element" in the module1 tree view. I made like below:

1. Add button with object action in the tree view:

   ```
   <button string="Add Entry" icon="STOCK_ADD" name="action_add_entry" type="object"/>
   ```
2. Define the action handler in module1:

   ```
   def action_add_entry(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
       '''
       This function opens a window to compose an meeting request
       '''
       assert len(ids) == 1, 'This option should only be used for a single id at a time.'

       ir_model_data = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
       try:
           compose_form_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'module2', 'module2_form_view')[1]
       except ValueError:
           compose_form_id = False 
       ctx = dict(context)
       ctx.update({
           'default_model': 'module1',
           'default_module1_id': ids[0],
       })
       return {
           'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
           'name':'Create Complaint',
           'view_type': 'form',
           'view_mode': 'form',
           'res_model': 'module2',
           'views': [(compose_form_id, 'form')],
           'view_id': False,
           'target': 'new',
           'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}},
           'context': ctx,
           'nodestroy': True
       }
   ```

I succeeded to get the form view displayed in popup but I did not get <kbd>Save & Close</kbd> button or the <kbd>Save & New</kbd>. I get only a <kbd>Save</kbd> button and a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> (which is not working).